# POST call not returning a result from REST API calling async function

Tags: c#, rest, api, asynchronous

We need to capture any client side errors happening in one of our third party web apps.
To do so, I have written an API Post call within one of our API controllers.
I used the below code in my API: 
(EnableCors is a part of nuget packages as system.web.cors which enables cors for API calls):

```
[EnableCors(origins: "/the client address that will call this API method", headers: "*", methods: "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT")]

[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage RecordLogMessage(EventLogSaveCommand eventLog)
{                  
    var result = await _mediator.SendAsync(eventLog);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

It is a POST method and I'm sending the command request to mediator's async message handler, the client call in chrome dev tools returns the "Provisional headers are shown", I suspected it might be addons that I installed on my Chrome browser, so I tried it in firefox and IE as well, they both return "Pending" status for the POST call and it seems that it is waiting for a return status code form host server.
While the event log has been inserted into data base and action is actually finished, but it's not able to return the OK (or created code, I tried both) status code to the client.
After searching on internet, I noticed that RESTFull API POST does not treat the async calls in the same way as sync calls so I had to replace the response code to "SeeOthers":

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, result);
```

But this did not help, as it caused even the mediator did not save the data in the database.

The second way I tried, I changed the mediator handler as a sync call, so I used mediator.Send(eventLog) and returned response status code as:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

This worked fine, client got the OK status code in respond.
But I want to know how can I use the mediator's async call and what is the problem with the result code, why is it not able to return the result even though it has successfully finished the command.

Also here is how I am calling this from client:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({message:"Test message", Uri:"Test url", source: "Test Source" , columnNo: "Test columnNo", error: "Test Error", lineNo: "Test Line No"});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://Myhost.com/api/CustomEventLog/RecordLogMessage/',
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    success: function(response){
    console.log("Error recorded in log table with id: "+ response);
    // alert(response);     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, For anyone who might be interested, I changed my POST call to be async call as well as below:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT")]        
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]    
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RecordLogMessage(EventLogSaveCommand eventLog)
{
        //var result = _mediator.Send(eventLog);

        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

        var result = await _mediator.SendAsync(eventLog);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, result);
}
```

This worked fine and client call had the result and new log was created as well.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a workaround but it's the correct way to do async in WebAPI.